# Adduser is not creating unique UIDs

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to create new system admin users with unique UIDs. However, when I run the command, it creates two users with the same UID (99):

```
[user@ip]/tmp% sudo adduser -r test1
[user@ip]/tmp% sudo adduser -r test2
[user@ip]/tmp% cat /etc/passwd | grep test
test1:x:99:216::/home/test1:/bin/bash
test2:x:99:215::/home/test2:/bin/bash
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser), it seems like I should have to supply the -o option to get the behavior above. Why is it producing users with the same UID?

Comment: What system are you running (version number and type, Linux, BSD, something else)?

Comment: Note that `-r` is for system users as in _used by programs_. It is _not_ for creating "admin" users.

Comment: @ojs: NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03

Comment: @grawity - Thanks, I understand that. I am trying to create users to run programs with a UID below 100, instead of yum creating the users with any UID.

Comment: why not just add users as normal, and set up sudoers to define what administration tools they can run?

Comment: Makes me wonder if the UID values have been restricted somehow in `/etc/login.defs`. Look there for `SYS_UID_MIN` and `SYS_UID_MAX`, see if they are the limiting factor here.

Comment: @strobelight - We manage user logins with a tool that regularly synchronizes users. In their onboarding instructions they have this statement: "Your system account must have a UID below 100, otherwise Singlepass will remove it." We are currently trying to fix the problem where yum creates the user and Singlepass deletes them, so the tasks cannot restart if terminated.

Comment: @ojs - /etc/login.defs does not have either of the SYS_UID_MIN or SYS_UID_MAX. From what I read, it should default to UID_MIN-1. Adding it explicitly seemed to fix the problem, (SYS_UID_MIN =1, SYS_UID_MAX = 99).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit /etc/login.defs and define SYS_UID_MIN and SYS_UID_MAX. In this case I used SYS_UID_MIN = 1, SYS_UID_MAX = 99 (note SYS_UID_MIN = 0 will not work).

Comment: Automated way of doing this: `sed -i -E \"s/(UID_MIN)(\s+)([0-9]+)/SYS_UID_MIN\\t\\t    1\\nSYS_UID_MAX\\t\\t   99\\n\1\2100/\" /etc/login.defs`